# How to multi-thread child_process.exec() in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, performance, child-process

I am currently building an application that uses `child_process.exec()`.
The issue I am running into is, upon concurrent requests, maybe my `exec()`s are being queued and due to which the responses are extremely slow.
How can I multi-thread `exec()` to solve this?

Comment: We can't answer questions like this without seeing the relevant portions of your actual code.  FYI, `child_process.exec()` already creates a new process which has its own thread so whatever issue you're having is probably about something else.  We will have a chance at helping you only when you show us all the relevant code and describe in detail exactly what problem you are having with that code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.